# Do I just need to include a .netrc file to have UNIX pick it up?

Tags: ftp

I have a .netrc with the following format in a directory using a bash terminal on OSX:

```
machine m...
    login l...
    password p...
```

I have chowned and cmoded the file like this, as suggested in [this help file](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.files/doc/aixfiles/netrc.htm)

```
$ chown myusername .netrc
$ chmod +600 .netrc
```

When I am in the directory, I issue the following command:

```
$ftp m...
```

Based on [this](http://www.mavetju.org/unix/netrc.php) tutorial (see section "useage of the .netrc") it seems like unix should automatically detect that there is a .netrc file in the directory when I type `ftp m..`, see that the .netrc gives credentials for machine . and pass them along to ftp.

This is not happening. Instead, I see this output

```
Connected to server.domain.com
220 Microsoft FTP Service
Name (file.server.domain.com:My_OSX_Username): #I would expect it would pull my username off the .netrc file
```

Am I using the .netrc file incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in general the `.netrc` file should just work as you've described. It might be getting blocked by your FTP client not supporting it (perhaps it was explicitly built without this feature enabled). This would likely be done since this method of storing usernames/passwords is inherently insecure and should likely not be used.

#### Checking with strace

You can always confirm what an application is doing by tracing it using the command line tool, `strace`.

```
$ strace -s 2000 -o ftp.log ftp m
```

After doing this you can analyze the log file, `ftp.log` to see if your `ftp` client is attempting to read the file `.netrc`. If it's working correctly you'll see this type of output in the log.

```
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_OOBINLINE, [1], 4) = 0
open("/home/saml/.netrc", O_RDONLY)     = 4
uname({sys="Linux", node="greeneggs.bubba.net", ...}) = 0
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=47, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4898b85000
read(4, "machine ftp.somedom.org\n\tlogin sam\n\tpassword blah\n", 4096) = 47
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=47, ...}) = 0
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
```

**NOTE:** In the above I'm connecting to `ftp.somedom.org` as user "sam" using password "blah". You can see that it read from my `.netrc` file.

#### ftp man page

If you take a look at the `ftp` man page there is this switch that's mentioned in my version:

```
 -n    Restrains ftp from attempting “auto-login” upon initial connection.  
       If auto-login is enabled, ftp will check the .netrc (see netrc(5)) 
       file in the user's home directory for an entry describing an account 
       on the remote machine.  If no entry exists, ftp will prompt for the 
       remote machine login name (default is the user identity on the local 
       machine), and, if necessary, prompt for a password and an account 
       with which to login.

 open host [port]
       Establish a connection to the specified host FTP server.  An optional 
       port number may be supplied, in which case, ftp will attempt to 
       contact an FTP server at that port.  If the auto-login option is on 
       (default), ftp will also attempt to automatically log the user in to 
       the FTP server (see below).
```

I'm on Fedora 19:

```
$ rpm -qi ftp
Name        : ftp
Version     : 0.17
Release     : 64.fc19
Architecture: x86_64
```